# How to handle name conflict with action in RESTful API

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

RESTful API should be focused on resource and not action.
However, when implementing RESTful on HTTP, due to the limited expressiveness of the HTTP methods, people add `[action]` to the end of the URL.

e.g.:
http://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/#operation/findPetsByStatus

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/

(DELETE /files/trash and GET /files/generateIds)

For API that the ID is defined by the user, the above design would lead to conflicts.

i.e. user creating a pet `findPetsByStatus` or a file `trash` or `generateIds`.

The API designer cannot prevent this from happening because we cannot foresee the future. i.e. we can't reserves all keywords that might be used as actions because the product evolves and changes over time.

Under this circumstances, how to design an API so we won't run into such problem?

I would like to follow OpenAPI spec but they disallow API with `/files?action=<someAction>`

Comment: First, applications following the REST architecture model don't care about URI design as they use an URI (=arbitrary token string) just to invoke the next possible action. Clients should use a relation name instead of analyzing URIs, which can be described either by a common standard (protocol, media type, ...) or by domain specific "knowledge". This helps servers to change URIs on the fly without breaking clients as they will just invoke URIs appropriate for a certain relation name. Next, how do restful URLs differ from non-restful ones?

Comment: Conforming to some standard such as OpenAPI enables the benefits you described (however it is still not easy to avoid breaking changes). The problem I have is that in OpenAPI spec I can't find a solution to describe the resources and actions in a manner that supports this circumstances (id is defined by the customer instead of a generated id).

Comment: You probably have a misconception of what a URI is. A URI is a token string that as a whole points to a certain resource. Segments of a URI do not necessarily point to ancestors of a resource so a URI like `www.example.org/a/b/c` does not state that `b` is a parent of `c`, though we usually interpret it as such and also structure the internal layout as such. But REST doesn't really care or depend on such. What you can do is to either neglect duplicate IDs or add some random value in between to make the URI unique again.

Answer (score 1):

> Under this circumstances, how to design an API so we won't run into such problem?

Change the stem; restrict the identifiers with user provided spellings to a different part of your endpoint hierarchy than the operations where you would need to worry about reserved words.

That is to say, you treat your URI space as a bunch of partitioned name spaces; you let your users customize the spellings in one name space, you put your api operations in another.  Ta-Da.

```
/b9d97060-d4db-4b20-a654-22bb0653db69/pets
/08f9a7c2-353b-484d-9e87-56acca4e5a57/pets
```

See?  No conflicts.

If somebody insists that all pet endpoints must be located under /pets, then just invert the ordering

```
/pets/b9d97060-d4db-4b20-a654-22bb0653db69
/pets/08f9a7c2-353b-484d-9e87-56acca4e5a57
```

Another possibility would be to host pet management on a different host than your pet utilities.

```
http://search.example.org/pets
http://api.example.org/pets
```

In a spelling argument, you might be able to find some support in the ubiquitous language of your domain.  For example, in a setting where you speak of consumers *registering* their pets, you could argue

```
/pets/registry
/pets/forms
```

separates the documents that describe the registered pets from the forms used to do interesting things with the registered pets.

```
/pets/registry/findPetsByStatus <-- the dog belonging to [Bobby Tables][1]
/pets/forms/findPetsByStatus <-- the documents used to integrate with the pets service
```

Don't get too caught up in the spelling debate -- loading a `/findPetsByStatusForm` and submitting it to get a `/findPetsByStatusReport` may [pass the noun test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Friends_episodes), but it doesn't improve the quality of the API.